# Lyapunov's stability example problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

Using definition of Lyapunov's stability, check if following solution is stable:
$$
\begin{cases}
& x'(t)=-x + t^2\\
& x(1) = 1
\end{cases}
$$

Now, I've solved the equation as I felt it was necessary:

$$
x' + x = t^2 \\
(xe^t)'=e^tt^2 \\
xe^t = e^t(t^2-2t+2) \\
x = t^2 -2t + 2 + ce^{-t}
$$
Plugging the initial condition $x(1)=1$ we get $c = 0$. Solution is then
$$
x(t) = t^2 -2t + 2
$$

I wish I could show anything more but I'm banging my head against the wall and can't find any meaningful examples what to do next.

My definition of Lyapunov's stability was given as:

> Stationary point $x_0$ is called stable when $\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{\delta > 0} \|x-x_0\| < \delta \implies$
>
> - $\varphi( ., x)$ is defined on $[0, \infty)$
> - $\|\varphi(t,x) - x_0\| < \epsilon \forall t \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the fact that you have been given the definition of stability of the equilibrium point, not stability of a solution in general, you are apparently expected to make a change of variables. Stability of the solution 
$$
x_s(t)=t^2-2t+2
$$
is equivalent to stability of equilibrium point $y_s=0$ of the system in variable $y(t)$,
$y(t)=x(t)-x_s(t)=x(t)-t^2+2t-2$.
The system in $y$ is
$$
y'= x'-2t+2=-x+t^2-2t+2=-y. 
$$
The solution of the initial value problem 
$$
y'=-y,\quad y(0)=y_0
$$ 
is $y=y_0 e^{-t}$. Its norm decreases for any $t$, thus, you can take $\delta=\epsilon$
in the definition to prove the stability of $y(t)=0$.

Comment: I got it all way until you performed this move: $\dots = -x+t^2-2t+2=-y$. Why is it equal to $-y$?

Comment: @Никита Васильев I substituted $x'$ from the original system. Since $x(t)$ is a solution of the original system, it satisfies $x'=-x+t^2$

Comment: That substitution is perfectly clear. I don't see why is it equal to $-y$ in the end. I would appreciate if you expained that.

Comment: @Никита Васильев  It equals to $-y$ because $y= y(t)=x(t)-x_s(t)=x(t)-t^2+2t-2$

Comment: Great, I think I get it. Thank you for your time!